# Send custom error message to div using ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

I would like to send custom message from ajax call to my bootstrap flash message where I'm displaying errors. Any idea?

Code below is not working.

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '{{ route('einsight.servicereports.validateDates') }}',
   cache: false,
   data: $(this).serialize(),
   success: function(data) {
       $('#form').html("<thead><tr><td>OK</td></tr>");
   },
   error: function(result){ 
        /* Custom message I want to send*/       
   }    });
```

html with laravel:

```
<div class="flash-message" id="error-message">
    @if ($errors->any())
    @endif
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the success part of your code to

```
error: function(data) {
   $('#error-message').html("bla");
```

},

and also you don't need the part

```
@if ($errors->any())
@endif
```